# Unable to recognise the properties of a third party grid contorl using IAccessible interface

Tags: winapi, user-interface, testing, automation, iaccessible

I have a grid control in my language which needs to be recognised as a grid (or table) control in order to get its all properties, when I'm using accexplorer32, it's recognising the grid as a valid table and giving back all properties, where I try to read these properties with api, it's giving an error, what could be theproblem?

Im using oleacc from system32 and trying to read properties using IAccessible interface.

Answer (score 0):

Random guess - did you CoInitialize()? Without this, some IAccessible stuff will work - mostly for plain HWNDs and the system-provided controls like buttons - so it's easy to forget it because lots of stuff works at first. But without it, custom IAccessibles won't work. (Also, what error are you getting? Always give as much information as possible in your SO questions!)